# Select first row on load of lazy p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Need some help selecting the PrimeFaces `p:dataTable` 1st row on page load, here's my code so far:

```html
<p:dataTable id="dtbList" value="#{Controller.items}" var="item" widgetVar="dataTableList" lazy="true" 
selection="#{Controller.selectedValue}" rowKey="#{item.key}" 
scrollable="true" scrollHeight="133">

<p:ajax event="rowSelectRadio" listener="#{Controller.handleSelectList}" update="dtbList" 
oncomplete="resetScroll();"/>
...
...
...
</p:dataTable>
```

I've tried using ajax event to no avail

```html
<p:ajax event="page" onsuccess="PF('dataTableList').selectRow(0);"/>
```

Wondering where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the rowKey (the id) of your first row try to add the property **dynamic="true"** in your dataTable component like this :

```
<p:dataTable id="dtbList"
value="#{Controller.items}" var="item"
widgetVar="dataTableList" lazy="true"
selection="#{Controller.selectedValue}"
rowKey="#{item.key}"
scrollable="true" scrollHeight="133"
dynamic="true">
...
...
...
</p:dataTable>
```

And, in your bean(Controller) create a method annotated by **@PostConstruct**, in witch you can select the best element.
Like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.selectedValue = new SelectedValueEntityType();
    this.selectedValue.setKey('yourKey');
}
```

Comment: As chances are high that a datasource is used to get items, and that there are many of them. Besides the fact that hardcoding an item is ugly, chances are that the item is not the first row (anymore) or not present at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `page` event is triggered on pagination, so not on the initial load.

You might want to make the controller a property of the `LazyDataModel` you've implemented (assuming you did; if you are using the `JpaLazyDataModel`, extend it). Now you can access the controller from the `load` method. You can now simply check if no selection was made and set the first item that was fetched in the `load` method as the selected item of the controller.

See also: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/datatable

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue before. And there is no direct way to do it since there is no listener for on load success in data table. So that to achieve same behavior do the following.

First of all, you will need to build `datatable` component programmatically.

For example, the backbean will be something like the following

```
public class Controller {
    private DataTable dataTable;
    private CustomLazyDataModel customLazyDataModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ExpressionFactory exFactory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getELContext();

        dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.setId("dtbList");
        dataTable.setValueExpression("value", exFactory.createValueExpression(elContext,"#{Controller.customLazyDataModel}", CustomLazyDataModel.class));
    
        // This for selecting first row.
        dataTable.setSelection(new YourPOJOClass[]{customLazyDataModel.getDatasource().get(0)}); 
    }
}
```

and here is an example of your custom lazydatamodel

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<YourPOJOClass> {
    // the loaded data source
    private List<YourPOJOClass> datasource;
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private boolean buildScreenPhase = false;

    // use this initialization function to create an instance of lazy
    // data model
    public static CustomLazyDataModel forBuildScreen() {
        CustomLazyDataModel customLazyDataModel = new CustomLazyDataModel();
        // pass needed data instead of null
        customLazyDataModel.load(0, 7, null, null, null);
        customLazyDataModel.buildScreenPhase = true;
        return customLazyDataModel;
    }

    @Override
    public List<RowModel> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
                      SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
        // Your loading logic here from db or something else

        // to enhance loading data performance we will use
        // buildScreenPhase flag
        
        if (!buildScreenPhase) {
            // load data
        } else {
            buildScreenPhase = false;
        }
    }

}
```